# CSS max-width not working

Tags: css

I have this code, but strangely the max-width and with property are not working:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <img src="imgs/topBar.png">
    <div id ="wrapper">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body img:first-child{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    margin:0;
    display: block;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 4px solid;
}
```

I made a http://jsfiddle.net/vkdbq/

Comment: Actually it is working.

Comment: Works for me. Although in the jfiddle you have the max-width set to 500, and in your code here it's 1200.

Comment: It is? i made the border to confirm that and on the right it disapears... does the same on chrome

Comment: If you want the border inside of the max-width, you need to set box-sizing:border-box;.

Comment: Thanks @Mastrianni, it solved the problem... Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Posted answer, can you mark as correct then please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set:

```
#wrapper {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 4px solid;
}
```